# Where to write database connection code in mvvm? And where to call it from?(wpf)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ado.net

I have to create a project in wpf ; but I have to use mvvm and I am not understanding where should I be writing the database connection code (ado.net), and how should I connect to it. How to achieve all this without no code behind? 
I have read a lot about mvvm wpf but I couldn't understand anything clearly.

Comment: try this link:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Comment: I wish there was some step by step tutorial for mvvm and wpf; this link helped a bit though

Comment: I'm far from being an expert on WPF. In fact, I'm kinda 1 step ahead of you - and I too see conflicting instructions everywhere. In Wikipedia they refer to the Model as the part that's responsible of the data. My team leader insist that the model should be a POCO, and data access should be handled in the ViewModel. (I've seen this approach in other places as well). Long story short, it's somewhat opened to interpretation. Whatever you do, as long is you don't put your data access in the view, I think you'll be fine.